# Parse xml data using multiple attributes in hadoop using pig or hive.

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Parse below mentioned type of xml in hadoop or pig

I tried with below script in pig or hive

```
PowerEvent sequence="00829" elapsedrealtime="0000047391" uptime="0000047391" timestamp="2016-01-17 00:31:36.750+0100" health="Good" level="69" plugged="NotPlugged" present="Present" status="NotCharging" temperature="23.0" voltage="3731" chargercurrent="25" batterycurrent="2209" coulombcounter="4294967292" screen="Off"

ConnectivityEvent sequence="00830" elapsedrealtime="0000047471" uptime="0000047471" timestamp="2016-01-17 00:31:36.831+0100" connected ="true" available="true" activenetwork="WIFI" mobiledata="Off" cellular="Unknown" operatorid="22210" operatorname="vodafone IT"
```

I tried with below script

```
register '/home/rajpsu03/pig/piggybank.jar'
xmldata = LOAD '/user/rajpsu03/pig/test.xml' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Events') as(doc:chararray);
data = foreach xmldata 
        GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'[\\s*\\S*]*<PowerEvent[\\s*\\S*]*sequence="(.*?)"[\\s*\\S*]*/>[\\s*\\S*]*<PowerEvent[\\s*\\S*]*elapsedrealtime="(.*?)"[\\s*\\S*]*/>[\\s*\\S*]*<PowerEvent[\\s*\\S*]*uptime="(.*?)"[\\s*\\S*]*/>')) AS (sequence:chararray,elapsedrealtime:chararray,uptime:chararray);
dump data;
```

Comment: is the input XML ? doesnt look like it. ?

Comment: <Event>
<PowerEvent sequence="00829" elapsedrealtime="0000047391" uptime="0000047391" timestamp="2016-01-17 00:31:36.750+0100" health="Good" level="69" plugged="NotPlugged" present="Present" status="NotCharging" temperature="23.0" voltage="3731" chargercurrent="25" batterycurrent="2209" coulombcounter="4294967292" screen="Off" />
<ConnectivityEvent sequence="00830" elapsedrealtime="0000047471" uptime="0000047471" timestamp="2016-01-17 00:31:36.831+0100" connected ="true" available="true" activenetwork="WIFI" mobiledata="Off" cellular="Unknown" operatorid="22210" operatorname="vodafone IT"/></>